# Clustered vertx event bus with Ignite cluster between 2 machines JVMs

Tags: javabeans, vert.x, ignite

I am trying to use a clustered event bus with Ignite cluster manager , clustered vertx itself  is working fine and clustered vertx web as well  right now I am struggling with clustered event bus in a cluster of 2 apache ignite JVMs on 2 separate machines

I know the following :

1-      We see in the documentation that Ignite cluster do the following for clustered Vertx : Cluster managers do not handle the event bus inter-node transport, this is done directly by Vert.x with TCP connections.

2-      The question now how we can handle properly the clustered vertx event bus between 2 different machines , clustered event bus need to know the public cluster host and public cluster port so from the attached configuration , can you please advise us how we can know the public cluster host and probably the port per node per machine so we can configure the same for the clustered vertx event bus over Ignite cluster ?

Between the 2 machines there is no firewall or VPN , the network is open between those 2 machines but the event bus is not able to establish the TCP connection properly between 2 machines as I am not able to see messages are going around between 2 machines and it is timed out very time :

Our cluster config is like that :

```
<property name="discoverySpi">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
        <property name="localPort" value="49500"/>
        <property name="localPortRange" value="20"/>
        <property name="ipFinder">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                <property name="addresses">
                    <list>
                        <value>IP1{machine one IP}:49500..49520</value>
                        <value>IP2{machine two IP}:49500..49520</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
```

And the see the consumer address registration is populated properly to all nodes

So what will be the proper configuration of the clustered event bus cluster host and port in each to make the cross machine TCP connection works fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vert.x doesn't use any Ignite configuration settings in event bus communication. The only thing that Vert.x does it store topics and subscribers in cluster manager (in Ignite cluster in your case). You should configure Vert.x event bus accordingly to documentation (http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#event_bus):

> The event bus configuration needs to be consistent in all the cluster
>   nodes.
>
> The `EventBusOptions` also lets you specify whether or not the event bus
>   is clustered, the port and host, as you would do with `setClustered`,
>   `getClusterHost` and `getClusterPort`.

You can't get Ignite nodes addresses until Vert.x cluster started. But you should provide Vert.x cluster host and port settings (see [VertxOptions.setClusterHost()](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/VertxOptions.html#setClusterHost-java.lang.String-) and [VertxOptions.setClusterPort()](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/VertxOptions.html#setClusterPort-int-)) before start clustered Vert.x instance.

Public cluster host and public cluster port should be provided only in case when used in containers.

Comment: Indeed that would be the fix to configure the VertxOptions.setClusterHost() and VertxOptions.setClusterPort())  in each node in each machine then the event bus will be working

Comment: I don't understand why Vertx can't handle it automatically